# VS Code: How to move selection horizontally

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

In VS Code's github a **move selection left and right** sort of action has been proposed and implemented back in 2016.

Here's the issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5251).

But I couldn't find the command.

The attached GIF shows clearly what I mean (I'm unfortunately still not allowed to upload images so here's the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgHRj.gif))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try set keyboard shortcut searching for Caret:

[image]

Comment: Great stuff, is it possible for vertical too?